# How to recover data from my flash drive that appears to be wiped out and which may potentially be infected with a Windows virus?

Tags: data-recovery, malware

I have a flash drive of 256GB with two partitions containing some important data. 
Today I had to connect my flash drive to my university's Windows computer to copy some files... but after connecting, all my data on both partitions were gone, and there are two files named **version.dll** and **USB driver.exe**... and also an **unnamed folder**... in each partition. 
I'm using Fedora 38.  How can I now recover my data?

Comment: Is that a regular flash drive, or one with extra security features? Or did you use [Bitlocker to Go](https://www.marquette.edu/its/help/security/bitlocker.shtml) or something similar to encrypt the flash drive? The apparent contents look similar to what a software-encrypted drive might legitimately look like when the (often Windows-only) encryption software is not present. Of course, it might also be malware pretending to be such an encrypted drive...

Comment: What is "an **unnamed folder**"? A directory *named* `unnamed`? A directory that appears to have no name?

Comment: Is that really `USB driver.exe` with a space in the name?

Comment: Have you tried asking your university’s IT support?